# What is this small tissue structure found in kidney?

Tags: endocrinology, histology

It's covered with white adipose tissue and it is smooth with reddish brown colour. HE dyed with dimensions 3 cm long and 1 cm wide. I'm guessing that this is a rare thing because I already checked pubmed etc. On the right is a closer picture of the tissue.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Voted to close because this sounds like a homework question - I don't think there would be another reason to ask this question unless you are a student - if you clarify otherwise I would consider retracting my vote. We aren't here to do your homework for you, I'm guessing if this was given as an assignment then part of your lesson was on this structure specifically.

Comment: You added that it is rare - what if it is actually very very normal? (where did you get the images from?)

Comment: Could you add a pointer?

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh It's the whole structure. The entire pink-tinted area on the top picture. (it's actually quite obvious I just don't want to give the OP the answer if this is homework...)

Comment: I can't find anything abnormal. Had a histology course recently so I'm curious if there's something I can't spot. @BryanKrause

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh That's because it's not abnormal.

Comment: It's the whole structure and this is not a homework. I saw this on webmicroscope and got really interested. I have been looking kidney histology articles and books and I have hard time figuring out what are these since i'm not studying medicine. Smooth structure made me think it could be multilocular cyst but i'm not sure and the sice of these is huge in kidneys.

Comment: Ok...hint: it's a gland. (and it's very normal to have these particular glands on your kidneys..)

Comment: @BryanKrause this is interesting. Suprarenal? aldosterone, cortisol etc...

Comment: Okey so they must be adrenal glands then. Why did I even think that these would have something to do with diseases...

Comment: @KatariinaJ. Bingo. If it makes you feel better, your description at the start was so spot on I assumed it was from a textbook question. If you read about adrenal glands they are often described precisely as being found under adipose tissue on top of the kidneys. The best identifying feature besides the location is the clear separation of tissue type into adrenal cortex and medulla, which are also quite distinct in function.

Comment: Thank you for helping me figure out this one with hints. This made me learn a lot. I was assuming way too many things.

Comment: @BryanKrause Please post an answer!

Comment: @canadianer Done. I like these IDs better than species IDs, those are too hard for me :-P

Comment: @BryanKrause Thanks +1. I do too. Wish there were more of them

Answer (score 3):

This is a slice of an [adrenal gland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adrenal_gland):

[image: Adrenal gland]

Source (Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike 3.0 License): http://histology.medicine.umich.edu/resources/endocrine-system

These glands sit on top of the kidneys, typically under adipose tissue (which can also be seen in both your image and the image I included here). The most identifying feature of the adrenal gland is its clear separation into two parts: the outer "cortex" and inner "medulla", as labeled on the image.

The two parts have different endocrine functions: the cortex primarily produces steroid hormones, like aldosterone and cortisol, whereas the medulla makes catecholamines epinephrine and norepinephrine (also called adrenaline and noradrenaline). I believe the inset in your image is of the medulla.